# Instead of editing the file in modified mode. used delete and create new file mode git

Tags: git

I checked out from master branch and I deleted a file and created a new file(instead of renaming the file). I have completed my feature but the problem is the master is several commits ahead and the the file I deleted has new updates.  and i can not manually do this because I have done this for several files. so is there a way I can map the files from two branches ( or change their mode). or is there a better way ?

Answer (score 0):

```
git stash
git merge master
git stash apply
```

then you can fix the issues if any, then commit.

Comment: I have lot of commits too. stash is when I have no commits right